# min-width works with td, but doesn't work with div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have existing tabs layout created with table. Due to new style requirement I cannot use this approach anymore. I am trying to switch to flex, but min-width idea I use with table doesn't work on div.

In my example below if you resize page paddings to the left and right of tab text are resizing (from 32px to 8px), but it doesn't happen for flex div layout.

```css
div.table-container, div.flex-container {
    min-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.left, td.right {
    min-width: 8px;
    width: 32px;
}

td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
td.left {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
td.content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.right {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
td.space {
    border-top: none;
    width: 4px;
}

div.flex {
    display: flex;
    gap: 4px;
}
div.tab {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: none;
    display: flex;
}
div.left, div.right {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 8px;
    width: 32px;
}
div.content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab QWERTY</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab ABCDEF</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab ZXCVBB</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab POIUYT</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab LKJHGF</td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab QWERTY</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab ABCDEF</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab ZXCVBB</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab POIUYT</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab LKJHGF</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It appears that your layout has unnecessary containers and complication. Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/ry6t85me/

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin in your example I can't configure dynamic space between tab text and left/right borders.

Comment: min-width is just that: the minimum width. It does not cause the element to shrink. The table element will shrink to fit inside the width of the viewport.

Comment: @TimR how can I achieve same result with something else? cause elements in a row to shrink between some max and min width, while other elements in the row remain the same size?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that only adds two declarations to the CSS. The main thing is to define a max-width for the tab. However, this may not work if the number of tabs will vary.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.tab {
  max-width: calc(20% - 3.2px);
}
```

Since there are five tabs, each one should have a max-width of 20%. However, you have to account for the gap. Four gaps at 4px each amounts to 16px. Divide by the number of tabs and subtract this value from the 20%.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.table-container, div.flex-container {
  min-width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 32px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.left, td.right {
  min-width: 8px;
  width: 32px;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
td.left {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
td.content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td.right {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
td.space {
  border-top: none;
  width: 4px;
}

div.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
}
div.tab {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  display: flex;
  max-width: calc(20% - 3.2px);
}
div.left, div.right {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 8px;
  width: 32px;
}
div.content {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab QWERTY</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab ABCDEF</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab ZXCVBB</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab POIUYT</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab LKJHGF</td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab QWERTY</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab ABCDEF</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab ZXCVBB</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab POIUYT</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="content">Tab LKJHGF</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's interesting. But tabs count is variable in my case. And for some reason text go overflow in your solution if I shrink window size to very small.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what I want with `flex-grow`/`flex-shrink`, `min-width`/`max-width`:

```css
div.table-container, div.flex-container {
    min-width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.left, td.right {
    min-width: 8px;
    width: 32px;
}

td {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
td.left {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
td.content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
td.right {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
td.space {
    border-top: none;
    width: 4px;
}

div.flex {
    display: flex;
}
div.tab {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
div.left, div.right {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 8px;
    max-width: 32px;
    flex: 1;
}
div.left {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
div.right {
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
div.content {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
div.gap {
    min-width: 4px;
    width: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab QWERTY</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab ABCDEF</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab ZXCVBB</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab POIUYT</td>
            <td class="right"></td>

            <td class="space"></td>

            <td class="left"></td>
            <td class="content">Tab LKJHGF</td>
            <td class="right"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex">
        <div class="tab left"></div>
        <div class="tab content">Tab QWERTY</div>
        <div class="tab right"></div>

        <div class="gap"></div>

        <div class="tab left"></div>
        <div class="tab content">Tab ABCDEF</div>
        <div class="tab right"></div>

        <div class="gap"></div>

        <div class="tab left"></div>
        <div class="tab content">Tab ZXCVBB</div>
        <div class="tab right"></div>

        <div class="gap"></div>

        <div class="tab left"></div>
        <div class="tab content">Tab POIUYT</div>
        <div class="tab right"></div>

        <div class="gap"></div>

        <div class="tab left"></div>
        <div class="tab content">Tab LKJHGF</div>
        <div class="tab right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```